# Bind 9.7 error with connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Tags: linux, dns

I'm having issue with one of my nameservers. When I'm using nslookup or dig without +trace, everything works fine. But when I'm using with +trace the error comes

> error with connection timed out; no servers could be reached.

This is lead my nameserver not update their records from master.
Below are my chechking:

```
1.============Iptables Stop==========
[root@dns2 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

2. ============Dig without +trace working==========
root@dns2 ~]# dig www.google.com +notrace

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P2-RedHat-9.7.0-17.P2.el5_9.1 <<>> www.google.com +notrace
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17007
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         74      IN      A       216.58.199.4

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             172572  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172572  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172572  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             172572  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 124.108.4.131#53(124.108.4.131)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 26 16:08:51 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 120

[root@dns2 ~]#


3.=============dig with +trace error=====
[root@dns2 ~]# dig www.google.com +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P2-RedHat-9.7.0-17.P2.el5_9.1 <<>> www.google.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.                       518076  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       518076  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
;; Received 508 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 1 ms



;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

===========================
```

Your response is being satisfied.